# How can I correctly retrieve the PID of a process related to Java using ps aux? and how can I put the headr containing the output column name?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, process, ps

I am not a system administrator (I am a software developer) and I have the following doubt.

Performing this command I can see the list of the first 10 process running on my system (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion):

```
MYSUER@MYHOST.it [~/FOLDER]# ps aux | head -10
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 191292  3892 ?        Ss    2021  21:29 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<    2021   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021   2:17 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021   0:10 [migration/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021  71:37 [rcu_sched]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<    2021   0:00 [lru-add-drain]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2021   0:56 [watchdog/0]
```

So the second column is the **PID** identifieng the process (I can use it to kill a process).

Then I tried to perform this command in order to retrieve all the running process related to **JAVA**:

```
MYSUER@MYHOST.spaccount.it [~/FOLDER]# ps aux | grep java
webadmin 22316  0.0  0.0 112812   980 pts/0    S+   18:21   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Basically I am filtering only the line related to java

And here a doubt. Tyhe **PID** is always the second column value?

Is it possible to put the header containing the column name as done in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **you do not use `ps aux` for that.**

Usually such processes would be run as *services,* and their PID tracked by the service manager (e.g. systemd; Upstart; supervisord; Monit...) If the goal is to check whether the service is running – the service manager can answer that. (For example, `systemctl is-active MyApp`.) If the goal is to restart the service if it crashes, or to prevent the service from being run twice – it's the service manager's job to do that.

In situations where the process cannot be run as service, its PID should be immediately recorded on startup *to a PID file* – either the app itself, or the launcher, can do this. (For example, `java -jar myapp.jar & echo $! > java.pid`.)

When you really need to search all running processes, use the `pgrep` command.  For example, to find all Java processes use `pgrep java` and to find all processes that mention MyApp.jar, use `pgrep -f MyApp.jar`. (Add the `-a` option to see the command, e.g. `pgrep -a java`.) This won't have the problem of returning grep itself, the way `ps|grep` does.

If you absolutely must use `ps`, then *specify the exact columns* that you want. Now the `u` option already requests a specific format, with certain columns in certain order – but if all you want is the PID, the `o` option lets you get just the PID. For example, `ps axo pid,cmd` always results in exactly two columns: the PID and the command, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

To find PID(s) only, `pgrep` is often better than `ps`.

Now I'm assuming you know what you want, you really want `ps` and you want the header. This particular task can be done with `sed`:

```
ps aux | sed -n '1p; /java/p'
```

Note your `ps … | grep …` probably finds the `grep` itself. Similarly my command finds the `sed`. You can avoid this by using a regex equivalent to `java` but not containing `java`. Example:

```
ps aux | sed -n '1p; /[j]ava/p'
```

---

If you want `grep` (e.g. because of its ability to add color), it may seem the following should work:

```
# flawed though, don't use it
ps aux | { head -n 1; grep '[j]ava'; }
```

It's flawed because `head` may read too much and there is no way to put excessively consumed data back for `grep` to read. `read` is better in this aspect, it reads one character at a time, so it can reliably read exactly one line:

```
ps aux | (IFS= read -r line; printf '%s\n' "$line"; grep '[j]ava')
```

Note I forced a subshell, so the variable dies with it and the main shell is not affected*.

---

<sup>* Shells are allowed to run the last part of a pipe not in a subshell or implicitly in a subshell. `read line` not in a subshell would set the `line` variable in the main shell. What if the variable is already there and holds an important value? By forcing a subshell we protect the state of the main shell, regardless of how the main shell behaves.</sup>